# Detect internet access in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tethering

My tethering app sometimes does not get internet access. In these cases Windows will not ask whether the app has permission to use the internet. My app generates no errors but of course will not tether.

How can I test whether my Delphi app has access to the internet sufficient for tethering?

Comment: Do you specifically look for a solution that works on Windows? And is it okay if the solution requires Windows Vista or newer or do you need to support older operating systems?

Comment: Is this a firemonkey app or a traditional Windows application and what exactly do you mean by "tethering"?

Comment: This is a Firemonkey app for Windows and Macintosh. I could be wrong but I'd like to think that there's a component somewhere that could simply check whether the app is online, for any platform. 
If you hover over the tethering tag above, it will give you a start on the meaning of tethering.

Comment: Do you mean detect network access?  Tethering is for local networks only right

Comment: Build yourself a server using the Datasnap server wizard. Host that server somewhere your clients can find it. Use a TSQLConnection, correctly configured, to connect to that server and determine it's accesibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should work on all platforms:

```
uses IdTCPClient;

function CheckInternet : Boolean;

var TCPClient : TIdTCPClient;

begin
  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create (NIL);

  try
    try
      TCPClient.ReadTimeout := 2000;
      TCPClient.ConnectTimeout := 2000;
      TCPClient.Port := 80;
      TCPClient.Host := 'google.com';
      TCPClient.Connect;
      TCPClient.Disconnect;
      Result := true;

      except
        Result := false;
      end; { try / except }

    finally
      TCPClient.Free;
    end; { try / finally }
end;
```

Source: [www.fmxexpress.com](http://www.fmxexpress.com/must-have-check-network-connectivity-state-library-for-delphi-xe8-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/)

A library to check for an Internet connection on mobile devices can be found at [www.delphiworlds.com](https://www.delphiworlds.com/2018/07/connectivity-checker-for-mobile-revisited/)